# Compilation error for emplace_back on templated constructor of a templated class

Tags: c++, templates

I am using https://github.com/ben-strasser/fast-cpp-csv-parser for parsing csv. I create a vector of CSVReader objects which I create using emplace_back (since copy, move are deleted). For some reason, the args passed in emplace_back is being read as `CSVReader` type in the templated constructor of CSVReader.

Reproducable code here: https://godbolt.org/z/Ps11EzbK9 (typed down below as well)

```cpp
// Type your code here, or load an example.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class LineReader {
public:
  LineReader() = delete;
  LineReader(const LineReader &) = delete;
  LineReader &operator=(const LineReader &) = delete;
  explicit LineReader(const char *file_name) {
    ;
  }
};

template <unsigned column_count>
class CSVReader {
private:
  LineReader in;
public:
  CSVReader() = delete;
  CSVReader(const CSVReader &) = delete;
  CSVReader &operator=(const CSVReader &);

  template <class... Args>
  explicit CSVReader(Args &&... args) : in(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {
  }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector <CSVReader<12>> vec;
    vec.emplace_back("hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve].  All code and errors should be in the question as formatted text and not just as links or images.

Comment: 1200 lines of code is not really minimal I guess

Comment: @mch You removed a lot more than `LineReader(const LineReader &) = delete;` in your linked to example.  You've basically changed the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that `CSVReader` is not usable in a `std::vector`.  When `std::vector` grows, it moves/copys the old buffer in to a new larger buffer by using the move/copy constrcutor of your class.  Therein lies the problem, `CSVReader` does not have a move or copy constructor.

The way normally solve this is to use a layer of indirection and have a vector of `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CSVReader<12>>>`.  Then you would add elements to the vector like    `vec.push_back(std::make_unique<CSVReader<12>>("hello world"));` as seen in this [live example](https://godbolt.org/z/rxsjcP3o5).

Comment: You beat me to the punch but I got this error as well in VS2019.

Comment: Got your point, but the compiler throws an error which threw me off guard and orthogonal.. 
error: no matching function for call to 'LineReader::LineReader(CSVReader<12>)'
why this error?

Comment: @Akash Because it tries to use the `CSVReader(Args &&... args)` to grow the vector when you add an element.

Comment: Shouldn't `Args &&...` template parameter for ctor of `CSVReader` result to `const char *` from main(). Are you trying to say, after it emplaces it, and tries to grow, it tries copying the existing obj data, and since Copy ctor is deleted, it uses CSVReader obj to construct from existing CSVReader using `CSVReader(Args &&... args)`

Comment: @Akash It's doesn't actually make a move/copy, since one is not needed, but there is code inside the `emplace_back` function to grow the vector if needed, and it is that code that causes the error even though it is not used at that exact moment.

Comment: Sorry, still confused, exactly when `Args = CSVReader<12>`. I am sending `Args = const char *`. Did you refer to the emplace_back lib code, can you link it here if possible?

Comment: @Akash In `emplace_back` there is code that checks if the buffer is full.  If it is, then it calls a grow buffer function that allocated new space and then moves/copies all of the old buffer into the new buffer.  It is that function that gives you and error because it tries to do `new (new_buffer + offeset) CSVReader<12>(std::move(*(old_buffer + offset));`.  That is where the `CSVReader<12>` gets passed to `CSVReader(Args &&... args)`.  That code is malformed because you don't have a copy or move constructor so the compiler throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

what happens is, that the adding of an element to "vec" tries to make a copy of your CSVReader, but that does not have an explicit copy constructor.
Then the compiler stumbles across the (only) Constructor template, which passes the arguments (here: the CSVReader to be copied) in the initialisation list into the construction of the "in" member, which of cause cannot handle a CSVReader (its only constructor takes a char*).

Solution: write a clean copy constructor, that properly initialises "in".